# Disable Android navigation in Kiosk Mode (Android Management API)

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, android-management-api

We have a Kiosk mode setup completed using Android Management API with our launcher app acting as kiosk app. However customizations applied through policy are not working as per expected.

```
"kioskCustomization": {
  "systemNavigation":"HOME_BUTTON_ONLY",
  "statusBar":"SYSTEM_INFO_ONLY",
  "deviceSettings":"SETTINGS_ACCESS_BLOCKED"
}
```

We have this in the policy and it is getting synced to device but still all buttons in navigation bar working and still we can able to access settings.
What we need to do in order to disable navigation bar in kiosk mode? If we have app in full screen it is just hiding them but not disabling them. 
Also is there way to disable gestures also?

Comment: Did you find out a solution to this? I am facing the same problem and apparently the `kioskCustomization` policy is only applied for the `kioskCustomLauncherEnabled` mode (but not for the `KIOSK` installType), which seems to be a bug to me

Comment: any update for this?, did you solve it? @H.T.Koo

Comment: Anyone heard anything else on this?

Answer (score 2):

I also noticed that when I applied:

```
"kioskCustomization": {
  "systemNavigation":"NAVIGATION_ENABLED"
}
```

That it didn't work when I had the `"installType":"KIOSK"` set for an app, so this might indeed be a bug. Are you in kiosk mode via installType, then?

A workaround is to set `"kioskCustomLauncherEnabled":true` and then manually launch the app. This sort of defeats the purpose of having an app that can launch into kiosk mode on boot, but I've noticed with my app that if I am in kiosk mode via `"kioskCustomLauncherEnabled":true`, then it will properly apply the kioskCustomization settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue for days! Finally found that it was the App I was using as my launcher app that was causing the issue.

For anyone else struggling with this, I suggest you set the Calculator app (`com.google.android.calculator`) as your Kiosk app and see if you're still getting the same issue. If not you know it's something to do with the app you're setting as the KIOSK app.

For me, the issue came from me including the following in the main actiivty intent-filter:

`category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"`

As soon as I removed that the `kioskCustomization` worked perfectly.